# What is the best report writer tool?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need to be able to print reports, general stuff.
But I need it to be simple, flexible, and light.
Reports must be independent from the application, and corrected and updated, by sending new report files.
A good extra would be allowing the user to creating basic/advanced reports, on there on.

Comment: Does the tool need to work with Delphi?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My favourites are [Fast Reports](http://fast-report.com/en/) and Excel.  I use fast reports for reports that are meant to be printed or pdfed and Excel for reports that clients can use as the base for further manipulation.

Fast reports files are xml.  They can be stored in a database or as files that can be independantly updated.  FR also includes an end-user report writer.  I have built this into some of my applications and it works well.

Comment: They also have a product named "Free Reports" which is a fairly old version of Fast Reports, without some of the new and awesome features.

Answer (score 4):

We have been a long time user of [Reportbuilder](http://www.digital-metaphors.com/). It is rock solid and the support is exceptional. Download the trial and give it a go.

If you are using SQL Server, another option will be to use SQL Server reporting Services.

Comment: +1 - I'm a big fan of Report Builder. Some of the demos and the docs could do with a spring clean, but the product itself is really, really good. I'm a paying customer and use it in almost everything I develop.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for FastReport, You can read more about reporting with Delphi on these threads:

[The best reporting component for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729399/the-best-reporting-component-for-delphi)

[Advanced report generation library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931296/advanced-report-generation-library)