# Document generator for DELPHI

Tags: delphi, document, generator

I need to allow my clients to generate documents (DOC, PDF, etc) from a DELPHI application I just released, based on information and data they have in the database.

The solution should be templates based. They must be able to edit and change the basic text and place to place replaceable “codes”

The generator must replace the code be database data and selected images, and export or print the result.

Is there a tool for this?

thanks

UPDATE  ----

I need to enable my client to generate their business proposal from my software. This is only text with photos, and simple replaceable codes.

But the photos are all over the text, they are needed to better illustrate the proposal.

But I need to allow the user to create or change the templates. This is where fastreport does not work. I don’t want to install or explain the client how to create reports in the designer.

Comment: you'll have to explain *something* to your client: Before you rule out something as powerful as Fast Report give it a honest chance. With Fast Report the end user can simply double-click an paragraph of text and change it, or double-click a image and change it. There's nothing difficult in that and the end user might not even need training. Don't get stuck in your "Replaceable Codes" idea. Fast Report has "Report Variables" that can be initialized from the Delphi application. It has many other useful things as well.

Comment: All the tests have done in this subject where in fastreport.
So far it’s the best solution.
Only the images and photos in the middle of the text are a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for some report generator, as they are called. [FastReport](http://www.fast-report.com/) is the one that comes to my mind - they have PDF and RTF generation for sure, and probably now have more.

Answer (score 1):

Even when I use FastReports myself, [ReportBuilder](http://www.digital-metaphors.com/) worths a mention here.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (I've used it like that), is to use **mail merge** in Word. Works great.

Easy solution: 
Save a .csv file, and trigger a mail merge with a certain word template via word's COM interface.
Instead of a .csv file you can also set up a data connection via odbc, but that's harder to install, and more likely to fail.

**Advantages** of mail merging:

- **Your client doesn't need a developer (*you =]*) to create or maintain templates.**  You can teach an average MsWord user how to create templates in a matter of minutes;
- Your client gets "normal" word documents as an output;
- Easy to implement;

Disadvantages:

- Certain things are difficult in word templates, like nested groups, so possibilities are not endless (like they would if you hand-roll some sort of report generator);
- Word needs to be installed on the machine where the reports are generated;

Comment: Nice suggestion, you just forgot the PDF generation request from the O.P.  I know there's solutions to this also after generating a word document, but I think O.P. is looking for a integrated PDF generation solution.

Comment: Yes. I like the mail merge approach, but the PDF is important.
And also the need for the ms Office to be installed. Some of my clients don’t have ms Office.

Comment: What about OpenOffice merge then? At least it's free if they don't already have it. The big advantage is that most users have at least seen a word processor before and have some idea how to use it.

Comment: You can get a free pdf printer driver.  And if they don't have a word license then you buy it for them. Whatever dude. It'll make them a happy client, and you'll earn that back in no-time with the time that you'll save with this approach. Now, and in the future, when they want their templates to be changed every other week.

Answer (score 0):

You need a report library like FastReports, RAVE, Greatis Print Suite, etc.. See this discussion: [The best reporting component for Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729399/the-best-reporting-component-for-delphi)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an Report Generator. You probably have one bundled with your Delphi IDE, can't tell you which one because they bundled different report generators over time.

Look for:

- [FastReports](http://www.fast-report.com/en/) - in my opinion, the best.
- [QuickReports](http://www.quickreport.co.uk/) - used to be bundled with Delphi.
- [Rave Reports](http://www.nevrona.com/) - used to be bundled with Delphi.

Any of those can give you grate printed and PDF reports. I think they're all capable of generating DOC "exports", but the quality will vary.