# Delphi: Display and Fill out Legal Forms or Reports

Tags: forms, delphi, report, edit

There are laws that have established forms of legal documents.

An idea is to create an application that can speed up a process of document creation, their filling out and submitting.

Like this:

[image]

How to show a form to fill out? What can I use for this purpose and what is better to use? Something like Excel...?

It would be excellent if it worked with `Firemonkey`.

**Requirements:**

**1)** A form mustn't be constant, an adding of additional fields must be supported (for example, there are 3 fields in an established form, but we have 4 items, so we need to add an additional one).

**2)** It would be great if we could add controls near fields, for example, a button to select an previously saved/entered address from a list.

**3)** Highlighting of fields (for example, highlighting of empty fields or with mistakes)

**4)** All forms will be stored in a database. The application must be capable to save an filled form to the database back.

Comment: There are plenty of applications that do this already. It may be possible to licence one to do your task.

Comment: Maybe this is in UK or USA, I'm talking about other countries :)

Comment: Does code written in the UK or USA not work in your country? I'm sure the one I know of would be happy to licence it anywhere! 8-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a look to FastReport. It can solve your 1/ & 3/ 4/ points, I am not sure for the other, but you may try the 'interactive report' in the demos.
Other informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729399/the-best-reporting-component-for-delphi).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can accomplish what you want with [RaveReports](http://nevrona.com/rave/)